# Windows 11 cannot recognize my USB-C earphone but can recognize its microphone

Tags: audio, windows-11, usb-c

I use ThinkPad X13 Gen2i and I have a HUAWEI CM33 USB-C earphone.

When I plug the earphone in, the sound cannot go from my earphone but still from my speakers.

But the sound output (microphone) have two choices: one is my earphone and another is my computer.

The reason why I can confirm that it is not my earphone's fault is that I have ArchLinux installed on the same computer and my earphone can be used properly on Linux system.

**What can I do if I use a earphone but the sound does not come out from it? I do not need its microphone!**

[image]

[image]

Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 23H2
Installed on    ‎2024-‎01-‎24
OS build    22635.3066
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22685.1000.0